# IOS 7 background data transfer launched within background Fetch, how is 30-second wall-clock calculated?

Tags: ios, xcode, background, fetch, appdelegate

Everyone,

I have searched a while and it appears I could not get answer to the following question:

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))fetchCompletionHandler
{
.....

NSURLSessionConfiguration  * config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"10-MIN-COREDATA-UPDATE" ];
     config.timeoutIntervalForRequest=150.0;
     config.timeoutIntervalForResource=2500.0;

```
 NSURLSession *  session=[NSURLSession  sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:  nil ];  
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *bgDownloadTask=[session downloadTaskWithURL:MyURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // use the downloaded file to update  a coredata  big table
    [self processFileAndUpdateCoreData];  // this may take long time
}] ;

[bgDownloadTask resume];
```

.....
}

I know background Fetch has a  wall clock of  30 seconds but I read  Background data transfer (NSURLSession) can download very large files and has no time limits in background mode, if I combine both of  these "background" modes into one call, how is  the  30-second wall clock calculated?  Suppose my  code finishes under  30 seconds before calling NSURLsession download (which takes long time to download AND Processing), is my background fetch call still under 30-seconds or I have well overused the allocated 30 seconds background call limit?  In another way,  how do I calculate time here? Should I  exclude  NSURL session time or  should I include it for the total time elapse for background Fetch call?

Any suggestions and  advices are greatly appreciated.

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried  MANY times and  launched a background NSURL session in app background refresh call, in NSURL session delegate I use the newly downloaded file to update a big core data schema, the app always  gets killed  in about 90 seconds.  So the answer is: 30 seconds wall clock applies no matter what  you do.